# how to create an autoclicker android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am a beginner on android. I would like to make an  **autoclicker** on android studio. An application that will click at a given location on the screen(inside my app), for example x=250, y=250.
i found many  script in this forum but i don't understand it.
i have the impression that it capture clicks made by the user but it don't make autoclick.but may be i am wrong.this is the **1rst code i found**

```
// Obtain MotionEvent object
view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
{
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(
            getApplicationContext(), 
            "View touched", 
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        );
        toast.show();

        return true;
    }
});


// Obtain MotionEvent object
long downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 100;
float x = 0.0f;
float y = 0.0f;
// List of meta states found here: developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#getMetaState()
int metaState = 0;
MotionEvent motionEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(
    downTime, 
    eventTime, 
    MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, 
    x, 
    y, 
    metaState
);

// Dispatch touch event to view
view.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);
```

**this is the second code i found**

```
private View.OnTouchListener handleTouch = new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        int x = (int) event.getX();
        int y = (int) event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                Log.i("TAG", "touched down");
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                Log.i("TAG", "moving: (" + x + ", " + y + ")");
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                Log.i("TAG", "touched up");
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }
};
```

**this code java is what i want to do but i don't know how to do the same in android studio**

```
package org.ea;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class AutoClicker implements KeyListener {
    static boolean enabled = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AutoClicker ac = new AutoClicker();
        try {

            JFrame f=new JFrame();
            f.addKeyListener(ac);
            f.setSize(100, 100);
            f.setVisible(true);

            Robot r = new Robot();
            int button = InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK;

            while (true) {
                if(enabled) {
                    System.out.println("Click");
                    r.mousePress(button);
                    Thread.sleep(400);
                    r.mouseRelease(button);
                }
                Thread.sleep( 2000);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The first code snippet does exactly what you want. You don't need to `setOnTouchListener` (that's just there to verify that it's being clicked), but the following code generates a click inside the view at the specified X and Y coordinates:

```
// Obtain MotionEvent object
long downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 100;
float x = 0.0f;
float y = 0.0f;
// List of meta states found here: developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#getMetaState()
int metaState = 0;
MotionEvent motionEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(
    downTime, 
    eventTime, 
    MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, 
    x, 
    y, 
    metaState
);

// Dispatch touch event to view
view.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);
```

Now, you just need to put it inside whatever logic you want to use to generate the clicks repeatedly

Comment: thank you i am very satisfied with your answer